# Phonegap app.initialize() only called when 1st run after install

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am following a PhoneGap bluetooth tutorial and it works wonderfully, except that app.initialize() is only called upon the very first app instantiation after intall. (I am currently testing only on Andriod). If I exit the app and restart it, .initialize() is NOT called; I must uninstall/reinstall the app. Obviously I don't want a user uninstalling/reinstalling the app to achieve init. Why will init not work except upon the first run after install? I do not believe this problem has anything to do with Bluetooth or serial functionality specifically, but for completeness I have included the JS file below:

```
/*
    SimpleSerial index.js
    Created 7 May 2013
    Modified 9 May 2013
    by Tom Igoe

*/

var PARTNER_NAME = 'HC-06';                                  // look for this Bluetooth partner name
var count = 0;

function findPartner(results) {

    for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        if(results[i].name == PARTNER_NAME) {
            count++;
            app.macAddress = results[i].address;            // get the MAC address
        }
    }

    if(count == 0) {
        alert('1')
    }
    else if(count > 1) {
        alert('2')
    }
    else {
        alert('3');
    }
}

var app = {
    macAddress: "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF",  // get your mac address from bluetoothSerial.list
    chars: "",

/*
    Application constructor
 */
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        console.log("Starting SimpleSerial app");
    },
/*
    bind any events that are required on startup to listeners:
*/
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        connectButton.addEventListener('touchend', app.manageConnection, false);
    },

/*
    this runs when the device is ready for user interaction:
*/
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        // check to see if Bluetooth is turned on.
        // this function is called only
        //if isEnabled(), below, returns success:
        var listPorts = function() {

            // list the available BT ports:
            bluetoothSerial.list(
                function(results) {

                    findPartner(results);
                },
                function(error) {
                    app.display(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            );
        }

        // if isEnabled returns failure, this function is called:
        var notEnabled = function() {
            app.display("Bluetooth is not enabled.")
        }

         // check if Bluetooth is on:
        bluetoothSerial.isEnabled(
            listPorts,
            notEnabled
        );
    },
/*
    Connects if not connected, and disconnects if connected:
*/
    manageConnection: function() {

        // connect() will get called only if isConnected() (below)
        // returns failure. In other words, if not connected, then connect:
        var connect = function () {
            // if not connected, do this:
            // clear the screen and display an attempt to connect
            app.clear();
            app.display("Attempting to connect. " +
                "Make sure the serial port is open on the target device.");
            // attempt to connect:
            bluetoothSerial.connect(
                app.macAddress,  // device to connect to
                app.openPort,    // start listening if you succeed
                app.showError    // show the error if you fail
            );
        };

        // disconnect() will get called only if isConnected() (below)
        // returns success  In other words, if  connected, then disconnect:
        var disconnect = function () {
            app.display("attempting to disconnect");
            // if connected, do this:
            bluetoothSerial.disconnect(
                app.closePort,     // stop listening to the port
                app.showError      // show the error if you fail
            );
        };

        // here's the real action of the manageConnection function:
        bluetoothSerial.isConnected(disconnect, connect);
    },
/*
    subscribes to a Bluetooth serial listener for newline
    and changes the button:
*/
    openPort: function() {
        // if you get a good Bluetooth serial connection:
        app.display("Connected to: " + app.macAddress);
        // change the button's name:
        connectButton.innerHTML = "Disconnect";
        // set up a listener to listen for newlines
        // and display any new data that's come in since
        // the last newline:
        bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n', function (data) {
            app.clear();
            app.display(data);
        });
    },

/*
    unsubscribes from any Bluetooth serial listener and changes the button:
*/
    closePort: function() {
        // if you get a good Bluetooth serial connection:
        app.display("Disconnected from: " + app.macAddress);
        // change the button's name:
        connectButton.innerHTML = "Connect";
        // unsubscribe from listening:
        bluetoothSerial.unsubscribe(
                function (data) {
                    app.display(data);
                },
                app.showError
        );
    },
/*
    appends @error to the message div:
*/
    showError: function(error) {
        app.display(error);
    },

/*
    appends @message to the message div:
*/
    display: function(message) {
        var display = document.getElementById("message"), // the message div
            lineBreak = document.createElement("br"),     // a line break
            label = document.createTextNode(message);     // create the label

        display.appendChild(lineBreak);          // add a line break
        display.appendChild(label);              // add the message node
    },
/*
    clears the message div:
*/
    clear: function() {
        var display = document.getElementById("message");
        display.innerHTML = "";
    }
};      // end of app
```

Comment: From where are you calling app.initialize()? Your question shows the initialize function, can you show us how you're using it?

Comment: app.initialize() is not called manually; it's part of the PhoneGap framework. Therein lies my problem....I don't control the framework and the triggers that call app.initialize().

Comment: I don't think that's actually true; it's generally called within a script tag in your index.html file (older versions of Cordova/PhoneGap) or at the bottom of the index.js file (newer versions). Can you point me to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: You are absolutely correct; thanks for pointing out my mistake. I now need to collect my thoughts to create a better case. Your input so far may already have set me on the right path.